# Не запускается и не устанавливаеться Linux(Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Читая книгу 'Хакинг искусство эксплоита 2 издание' у меня появилась задача установить Ubuntu но не обычную, а сделанную самим автором книги. Я решил установить её на 'VMware Workstation Pro', то есть обычный эмулятор. Но вот при выборе LiveCD появилась ошибка '[image: введите сюда описание изображения]' вопрос что делать? Надеюсь есть люди которые знают решение этой проблемы. Заранее спасибо! Дополнительная информация меню [image: введите сюда описание изображения] [сам диск](https://www.books.ru/library/hacking-2ed/disk.iso)

Comment: 1-й скрин - это типа BSoD'а на винде. Почему оно падает в крнелпаник на виртуалке - вопрос очень интересный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй через QEMU.
Вот запустилось: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1wOC.jpg

Ну или на крайний случай запиши iso на флешку и загрузись в live режиме.